# Lambda execution failed with status 200 due to customer function, error task timed out

Tags: javascript, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cloudwatch

In my project i am using lambda function with the timeout configuration for 25 seconds.
If i didn't hit any api's for sometime and after that if i hit the api , the time exceeds 25 seconds and throwing me Time out error(Internal server error) in postman.And after that if i hit api's it is working.

To avoid cold start i am using lambda ping using cloudwatch event rule which is triggered for every one minute.

If i speak about logs in cloudwatch , i am getting logs upto certain program flow and it stops.But the point where the program flow stops differs for each time , from this i probably can confirm that there is no problem where the code goes wrong.

I am using javascript formy project.

Answer (score 0):

Cloudwatch Events to keep a lambda warm are great, but only do so much.

If you make a deployment to your lambda, it starts a new Version, and that version hasn't started up yet so it may still encounter the Cold Start

If your lambda is getting hit hard and has lots of invocations, AWS will provision a second concurrent execution, and this will get hit with the Cold Start

And a few other less likely scenarios, but in effect you still hit the cold start. Somewhere, somehow, a cold start has to happen.

You have two options: 1) increase the timeout of your lambda. But likely, given that you are already up to 25 seconds, you should probably be considering breaking this into multiple lambdas, using a Step Function if you have a flow, or figuring out event driven activation of the various components

2. adjust your Provisioned Concurrency. This value, along with cloud watch events, is the most useful part of keeping lambdas warm - it is saying 'Hey, always have at least this many concurrent executions going at a given time'

Comment: Actually i am using lambda ping which is triggered for every one minute , so the lambda should always be warm right. Still i am facing the issue while i hitting api after some idle time(lets say 10 mins).

Comment: should is always a dangerous word ;) There are plenty of situations (Some of which i outlined) where that lambda ping doesn't quite mean its warm - at somepoint, somewhere, it has to have a cold start somewhere. (Its a major issue Im working around too at work - we have to have a reliable sub 3 second response in a step function of 15 lambdas - our 99th percentile is about 6 seconds, and thats entirely due to occasional cold starts - and we're receiving millions of requests to our system a day)

Comment: it is a well known issue with lambdas that is actively being developed around by tons of companies and AWS. Provisioned Concurrency is a bit safer and has less cold start times than pings, and there is another solution where you use cloudwatch alerts to pre-emptively start up additional lambda concurrency when you start to see an increase in traffic (and then lower when you dont have as many)